# Problems with imported model animation from Blender to Unity

Tags: animation, unity, models, blender

I've downloaded a free sculpted arm and created my own rig and animation for it in Blender. So here is how it looks like in Blender :

[image]

And the model itself looks fine in Unity, but as soon as the animation starts, the vertices are partially glued together like this :

[image]

I've simply imported the .blend file for the moment, is there some better way to import this?

Comment: Well okay, I just noticed that this bug seems just to happen in the Unity game preview. The built game looks fine...

Comment: Maybe wrong direction of the vertices or wrong order? Have you checked if unity is able to interpret .blend as far as I know it understand fbx  that's all

Comment: .blend shouldn't be a problem according to this : http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html . I guess this is just some internal issue, since it's looking fine in the built project.